# JavaScript function won't work on phone

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, phonegap-build

I have this script:

```
function isitvisible() {
    var style = document.getElementById('product').style;
    if (style.visibility === 'hidden') {
        style.visibility = 'visible';
    } else { 
        style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }       
}
```

And this part of the HTML that i want to hide or show:

```
<div id="product">
    <div ng-repeat="producto in productos">    
        <div class="figuranta" id="{{ producto.id }}" >
            <figure class="floating" id="{{ producto.id }}" onclick="details(id);">
              <img ng-src="{{ producto.image }}" alt="image" class="rcorners3 img-responsive"  alt="Null">
              <figcaption> {{ producto.name }}</figcaption>
            </figure>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Eeverything works perfectly fine when trying it on Chrome (hides the whole "product" div), however when opening it in the phonegap app won't work as expected. Instead of hiding or showing the whole div, what it does is hiding/showing the text in the `<fig caption>`.

Comment: Did you try ng-show/ng-hide instead of getting the dom element ? In addition you should also use ng-click instead of onclick. and you're actually give some div the same id, which is not authorized in HTML.

Comment: @Okazari, that `ng-` stuff is Angular. It appears this user is too new.